# VB6 compiled is slow when copying files

Tags: vb6

I know, VB6 is historic...ok, but...
I w
rote years ago a backup program not being satisfied from coomercial producuts I tested.

Now I wanted to renew it with some enhancements and a new graphic; the result is quite good for me. Since the file copying process is generally rather slow, I thought to compile it to squeeze some seconds...and instead...this is much slower.

Here are some info:

- Win10-64 (version 22H2 just upgraded)
- Tested on the same PC with identical parameters
- VB6 runs with admin privileges, in Win7 SP3 compatibility mode.

Even if it is not relevant here, the job was to copy a folder containing other 426 folders and 4598 files of different sizes (from 1kB to 435MB, for a total of 1.05GB), from an inside SSD disk to an external SSD disk.
*The interpreted version took 7.2 sec while the compiled version ended in 18.6 sec !*

I tried different compilation setting in native code, dismissing all the advanced controls over ranges, integers and floats, without any notable difference.

I could accept a small difference for some unknown reason, but it is unreal to get a 2.5:1 ratio.

Any idea?

**EDIT**
Based on comments:

- I repeated the comparison several times; the differences (in both the compiled and the interpreted mode) is around +/- 1sec.
- Files are copied using filesystemobject.copyfile
- my admin privileges are the same for both

Again, I'm not complaining nor worried by the absolute time the copy takes, I can survive with that since it is an operation made every week and during easy hours.
What is surprising is **WHY** it happens.
Even the idea to compile the program was due to my curiosity since there is very little to optimize in the code; it is just a for-next loop with very little calculations and assignements.
The program takes the dir and files info from a text-based DB created by recursively scanning of the source folder, then loaded into a custom array...pretty simple.
This is done before the actual copy phase, which is what I'm investigating.

Comment: File and directory ops are strongly I/O bound, so the method of compilation should have little effect. Caching can disrupt attempts to compare file operations. When making such comparisons, be sure to try each in a fresh environment, ideally after a reboot.

Comment: Exact HOW do you copy the files? API Calls? Open/Get/Put/Close with binary files?

Comment: I typically don't recommend doing this, but it might be worth to check out Windows' own Robocopy and instead having _your_ program do the actual file copying, create the appropriate command line and launch RoboCopy and let it do the job.

Comment: Have you run this test / comparison multiple times to get meaningful results?  Like if something else was running at the same time and hogging the disk?

Comment: Did your complied program also run as admin with the same settings?